# Display/Monitor recommendations for the new MacBook Pro 14” M1 Pro

Tags: monitors, displays, macbook

I recently purchased a MacBook Pro 14” M1 Pro (2021 model) and looking to get an external monitor for it.

I’m looking at probably a 27-34” screen size at 4K, as my previous monitor was an old 2012 iMac (using target display mode, but that is not compatible with the new Macs).

I’ve been looking online for recommended monitors, but having trouble finding any ones which are proven to work optimally. Reviews seem to be very mixed. I was looking at the following:

1. LG UltraFine Display 32UL950
2. LG UltraWide 34WK95U
3. Dell U2720Q

Most reviews appear to mention that connecting the MBP from usb to mini display doesn’t provide a great resolution and text can either be fuzzy or too small.

If anyone has any recommendations on monitors which they use with an MBP 2021 model, I’d love recommendations. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Philips 276E8VJSB (+-€300), which seems to fit all your requirements:

- 27inch 4K
- Compatible with the newest macbooks (over HDMI)

And as a bonus it has an Excellent choice award on Hardware.info: https://nl.hardware.info/monitoren.8/philips-276e8vjsb.490721 (Dutch only)

About the monitors you posted:

LG Ultrasharp, Much more expensive and not much better

LG Ultrawide, I won't trust to get 60Hz over HDMI (and still much more expensive than the Phillips)

Dell: If you need HDR, this is a good option, but its not really good HDR